# Аргумент типа "const char *" несовместим с параметром типа "LPCWSTR" VS 2015

Tags: c++

В свойствах проекта [image: проекта]
код:
[image: code]
В чем проблема?
В проекте с гитхаба как видно SetConsoleTitle принимает const char * без ругательства
[image: git]

Comment: Уж сколько раз твердили миру: **не размещайте изображения на внешних хостингах**! И что теперь? Изображений нет ни у самого ВКонтакте, ни у Internet Archive Wayback Machine. А без изображений вопрос потерял всякий смысл.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что он хочет `wchar_t`.

> ```
> ...("")
> ```

```
...(L"")
```

Comment: я брал проект с гитхаба и там не возникала ошибка

Comment: @Player: Так не бывает.

Comment: @Ant если бы так не было то этого вопроса не было бы

Answer (score 3):

`LPCWSTR` является объявлением typedef для типа `const WCHAR *` .

```
typedef _Null_terminated_ CONST WCHAR *LPCWSTR, *PCWSTR;
```

Нет неявного преобразования из типа `const char *` в тип `const WCAHR *` Вы должны себе отдавать отчет, какие вы типы в своей программе используете.

Если в качестве аргумента используется строковый литерал, то используйте перед ним префикс `L`, например, `L"literal"`.

Comment: мне нужно именно SetConsoleTitle("") и ни как больше

Answer (score 2):

Достаточно просто отключить "использование многобайтовой кодировки" в найстройках проекта (на той же странице) и функция начнет спокойно принимать ваш литерал.

Пояснение: функции `SetConsoleTitle` не существует, это дефайн вида:

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
    #define SetConsoleTitle SetConsoleTitleW
#else
    #define SetConsoleTitle SetConsoleTitleA
#endif
```

Когда вы в настройках проекта включаете "многобайтовую кодировку", обявляется константа препроцессора и все `SetConsoleTitle` становятся `SetConsoleTitleW` и требуют на вход `LPCWSTR` вместо `LPCTSTR`. Иначе - `SetConsoleTitleA`.

Comment: с отключенной многобайтовой кодировкой тот же результат

Comment: @Player попробуйте напрямую SetConsoleTitleA

Comment: мне нужно именно SetConsoleTitle и ни как больше

Comment: @Player Этому есть разумное обоснование? Тогда разберитесь с юникодовыми дефайнами в своем проекте.

Comment: Интересно как он это сделал

Answer (score 0):

Надо просто явно вызывать нужный метод: либо `SetConsoleTitleW`, либо `SetConsoleTitleA`.

Comment: мне нужно именно SetConsoleTitle и ни как больше